# Read output from console dialog box

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, buffer, stdout

I want to get output text from the external process that runs the application and this application displays something that looks like a console dialog box like in the screenshot below:

[image: External application]

I tried to get output via StandardOutput:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = pathToExeFile,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    },
};

process.Start();

var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

process.WaitForExit();
```

But in this case both `output` and `err` variables have null values only. I assume that this is because the output from the app is not available via stdout but from something which looks like a dialogbox/messagebox. Is there any way to get this output?

Comment: This looks like an app writing directly to the text buffer. There is a Microsoft Research project [Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) that will allow intercepting such writes. Not for beginners.

Comment: @DourHighArch do you mean by that I have to read text directly from the console buffer in that case?